# What is a good search technology to use for indexing documents and text

Tags: c#, asp.net, search-engine, search

What tools are out on the market that can index documents and text?

Ideally they need to fall into these categories.....

- Be able to work within medium trust
- Be open sourced
- Be able to analyse and strip out the text from documents (pdf/office docs/docx)
- Be able to create snippets and highlight from search terms
- Be able to search fuzzy, phrases etc

Any useful information would also be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it works within medium trust and fits all of you requirements, but have a look at [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't open source, but you may want to look at [Zoom Website Search Tool](http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/index.html)